# On first look it seemed StackOverflow was sponsoring the V8Supercars in Townsville

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

Especially on TV the [Sucrogen](http://www.sucrogen.com/) logo was very reminiscent of SO's, except (now that I checked on-line) it is in reverse.

Comment: It's not similar at all IMO

Comment: I agree online they're not very similar, but in the graphic used on TV when the Sucrogen chopper shot was shown, even in HD Digital, the bars below the horizontal could hardly be distinguished. Of course if the SO logo was on the screen at the same time I'm sure I'd distinguish them, even if it was the mirror image to make the "spiral" go in the same direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We only sponsor unicorns.

[image]